# Location of the site creator

Tags: website-design, gui-design, layout, ux-designer

I want to add "created by @my_name" or "by @my_name" but I don't want to put it in the footer or some other inconspicuous place. I decided to make this "fixed" on screen, but do not know where it is better to put.

Options:

- bottom left corner
- top right corner
- bottom right corner
- top left corner

What place will be the best? (Or another option or some site example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is why you *need* your name and credit to be so visible on this website.

Having the creator's name in the footer is standard, and leaves the website completely unobstructed or de-emphasized by some tag with the creator's name. Typically, people who want to know who created the site will look in the footer. These people don't make a large percentage of visitors (usually), so it makes no sense to force information on the visitor who will ignore it either way.

I'd also make sure adding your credit on the site is in your contract with the client. Otherwise it could be [rather rude](https://yoast.com/footer-design-by-links/).

If you insist on adding it though, there are [many creative ways to add a footer](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/website-footers-1131597).

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) they will give you a warning when the element overlaps a "tap target." As long as it doesn't overlap, you can put it anywhere. I tend to go for the bottom left for fixed footer elements (my branding), however in general it doesn't offer a ton of value.

Imagine coming back to the site again and again (which is often what you want) and having this static thing sitting there (like a navigational element).

On desktop it can be made much more subtle but I'd try to avoid having it static on mobile.